# MySQL using GROUP_CONCAT field in MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables: loinc and panels. I currently have a successful GROUP_CONCAT and MATCH AGAINST query working.  Shortened a bit:

```
SELECT LOINC_NUM as ln,LONG_COMMON_NAME,SYSTEM,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(PARENT_NAME) from panels WHERE LOINC_NUM = ln) as PANEL_STRING,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(PARENT_LOINC) from panels WHERE LOINC_NUM = ln) as PANEL_LOINC_STRING,
MATCH (SYSTEM,LONG_COMMON_NAME) 
AGAINST ('string' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM loinc 
WHERE MATCH(SYSTEM,LONG_COMMON_NAME) 
AGAINST ('string' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 100
```

However, if I would also like to MATCH against the PANEL_STRING 'field' (which is a GROUP_CONCAT) as well. I have found elsewhere that I can change the subquery to a join, however that seems to be returning only a single line as not every line in loinc joins to a panel.

Anyone willing to help me out and show me how I may be able to make the GROUP_CONCAT field one that I can use for MATCH AGAINST searching? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your panel name is the hierarchy ID (like 001.007.0014), you could create a GROUP_CONCAT that starts with the hierarchy ID, then adds the LOINC number or LOINC Part number at the end (like 001.007.014:LP7407-7 and 001.007.014:9987-6). With that GROUP_CONCAT, you can search on whole sections of panels or just the individual LOINC or LOINC Part.